# PySide Dialog return values on accept

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm making a Dialog that returns a dictionary to a function. However the input needs to be validated before it can be processed.

I'm using the following code to run the Dialog and return the dictionary:

```
if transadd.exec_():
        knowns = transadd.widg.get_values()
```

with widg being the Dialog and transadd being a widget holding the Dialog.

get_values simply runs through all the comboboxes and adds their values to a dictionary:

```
def get_values(self):
    for key in self.unknowns:
        self.unknowns[key] = self.unknown_trans[key][1].currentText()

    return self.unknowns
```

Lastly I have a validation method which replaces is activated when a user clicks 'OK':

```
def validate(self, Dialog):
    counting = 1
    Errored = False
    for key in self.unknowns:
        if self.unknown_trans[key][1].currentText() == "Please Select..." and \
                self.gridLayout.itemAtPosition(counting, 3) != 0:
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(
                QtGui.QLabel("Missing Answer", Dialog),
                counting, 3, 1, 1
                )
            Errored = True
            self.sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                                QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        counting += 1
    if not Errored:
        Dialog.accept()
```

Currently all the above works exactly how I want it to. The problem comes when the user clicks on the cancel Dialog (rejected()). In this case the validation doesn't occur because we are cancelling which is fine. But get_values is still run due to the first portion of code - which would in turn run the rest of the function and would create a inaccurate output.

So my question is: How can I make a Dialog box return values only when the user clicks accept as opposed to reject?

Comment: Why do you have a dialog within a widget?

Comment: Because of the QtDesigner export. Probably a bit excessive but I made a wrapper class - as a widget - which takes an exported Dialog class from QtDesigner and runs it. Would that have an impact on the above?

Comment: I suppose you are getting this because you are running exec_() on the holder, whereas the logic (accept/reject) happens in transadd.widg; not certain without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you don't run a dialog in the standard manner (a top-level modal widget), you can still access whether it was accepted or rejected using the result:

```
transadd.widg.result()
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go when I get home.

Comment: Thanks - found out I wasn't having a problem with this at all but your suggestion helped me debug to come to that conclusion.